# PHP Getting formatted text into MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo, textarea

I've been trying to get some formatted people's descriptions into PHPMyadmin.

However, I've encountered two issues:

The first was with whitespace. It seems that the nl2br function solves this in part.

However, quotes seem to cause a problem and the function used to escape strings for PDO statements still leaves the quotes as â€. What am I doing wrong here ? What is the solution ?

description corresponds to user input in a textarea :

```
$req = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO people(fullname , description) VALUES(?,?)');
$req->execute(array($post['fullname'],$db->quote(nl2br($post['description']))));
```

Also, I've seen some much more complex textAreas used for forums posts (such as this one). Are those custom written ? Are any freely available on the Internet? Or is it some html feature which for some unfathomable reason my html book hasn't bothered to mention?

Anyway, thanks a lot.

spliblib

Comment: "still leaves the quotes as â€" - seems like a character encoding issue. Are your database, PDO, and input method all configured to use the same character set? (UTF-8 for example)

Comment: As you use `$db->prepare(..)` there no need for `$db->quote(..)`, so correct statement:
`$req->execute(array($post['fullname'], nl2br($post['description'])));`

Answer (score 0):

Mostly used for extending the textarea's functionality: [ckEditor](http://ckeditor.com).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set the database character set to utf-8 before inserting your records. Run the query below before any INSERT query.

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

Since you are using PDO, you can do something like this:

```
$pdo = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=mysql.example.com;dbname=example_db',
    "username",
    "password",
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

Regarding the 'complex textareas', these are called WYSIWYG editors ( an acronym for "What You See Is What You Get"). The popular ones are:

1. [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)( Used by WordPress)
2. [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/)
3. [wymeditor](http://www.wymeditor.org/)
4. [WMD Markdown Editor](http://wmd-editor.com/) (Used by StackOverFlow)

Comment: PHPmyadmin's character set is utf8_general_ci.

Adding charset=utf8 to the PDO database declaration generates an

 SQLSTATE[HY000] [2019] Unknown character set

error.

Comment: Actually, never mind. I've just inserted "'"'é"'é"'é(çèé) into my database. I'll try and reproduce the error mentioned above, but I'm not sure why I'm not getting it anymore.